# Getting single integer from database cast error

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to get one Integer from my database passed back to me as the following (I know it will be unique):

```
  Dim SequenceyQuery = From a In db.ServiceSequences
                            Where (a.ServiceId = ReqService And a.StationId = AtStation)
                            Select a.Sequence

  Dim TempSequence As Integer = CInt(SequenceyQuery.ToString)
```

But am getting problems trying to cast it in the second line of code. Is this the best way to get that integer from here and how to I get it as an integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not call `ToString()` on your query.

Call [`First()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx) instead, which will return the first element.

```
Dim TempSequence As Integer = SequenceyQuery.First()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `FirestOrDefault()`

```
Dim SequenceyQuery = From a In db.ServiceSequences
                     Where (a.ServiceId = ReqService And a.StationId = AtStation)
                     .FirstOrDefault()

Dim TempSequence As Integer = SequenceyQuery.Sequence
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Dim SequenceyQuery = (From a In db.ServiceSequences
                        Where (a.ServiceId = ReqService And a.StationId = AtStation)
                        Select a.Sequence).FirstOrDefault()
```

or u can use First() instead